# How to add to blade (Laravel, PHP) PHP-code as text with other background?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9, php-8.1

I want add PHP-code as text in laravel blade. (Something like adding code in stackoverflow)

in blade file I have:

```
{!! nl2br($article->body_ru) !!}
```

in $article->body_ru I'm add

```
huijlhgfyuhukik
rfthkgjb
ftygyjh
<code>
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use stdClass;

class WeatherService
{

}
</code>
```

And I'm want to see something like this in body:

huijlhgfyuhukik
rfthkgjb
ftygyjh

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use stdClass;

class WeatherService
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I am unable to completely understand what you are trying to achieve here.
If you could elaborate, that might help people in answering with some relevant work-around.

If you just want to print this in the output: "huijlhgfyuhukik rfthkgjb ftygyjh"

Put this text in a compact variable, let's call it $output.

```
function index() {
    $output = "huijlhgfyuhukik rfthkgjb ftygyjh";
    return compact( 'output' );
}
```

And use it in the blade file like this:

```
{!! $output !!}
```

Comment: I want to show PHP-code like a text with this 'words', not only this words.

Answer (score 0):

Blade files get compiled to raw PHP files and they can contain PHP. This would be the same exact thing if you had a regular PHP file and you wanted to output that text. You **could** use a HTML entity, `&lt;`, instead of the opening `<` for the `<?php` tag so it doesn't go into PHP mode and will be rendered as `<` in the HTML by the browser:

```
<code>
&lt;?php
...
</code>
```

Comment: Maybe you know...What I can do with tabs in code? How to show tabs in text?